# Laravel database, what data type should I use to store a passport number?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-migrations

I'm in the process of developing a Client Registration page for a travel agent. The client needs to save the passport number as a record in the MySQL database. I would like to know the data type ideal for mentioning in the migrations page for storing a Passport number. Usually, a passport number contains one or two English Letters and a few digits.

```
Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('surname');
    $table->string('other_names')
    $table->date('dob');
    $table-> ?? ('ppt_no');
```

Comment: Are you planning on just storing the passport number or are you going to be encrypting them?

Comment: Just storing the passport numbers for the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really [encrypt](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/encryption) them before the application goes into production. Otherwise, you probably want an alphanumeric column, like CHAR(9) or VARCHAR(9).

```
$table->string('passport_number', 9)->unique();
```